# How to remove Inline CSS using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have

```
<div class="slide slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0"
aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1730px; position: relative; left: 0px; top:
0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide00" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control00">
```

I want to remove `z-index`, I tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery('.slick-slide).css('z-index', "");
});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery('.slick-slide).css('z-index', "auto");
});
```

and I tried all the classes listed in the div above, nothing worked. I just want to remove the `z-index`, it's a wordpress site, so using JS/JQuery are my only options.

Comment: Try using !important

Comment: If your code is a direct copy and paste to here, try adding the missing quotes also.

Comment: are you sure the slick slide libray isn't adding z-index when it runs? so even if you remove the z-index, the library may add it back a while later.

Comment: @bitten Nothing worked, I tried all the answers and comments, I guess you are correct, what to do in that case?

Comment: Try `.style.zIndex = "";`

Comment: Did you try setting z-index to a different value with `!important`? If nothing else works, you could copy and overwrite the library css if you have access to it and just remove the problem part.

Comment: @Tim Yes I tried important, did not work, I don't have ftp access, requested it. but I think if I should remove the code, I need DB access because thats how most of wordpress plugins work, they store their code in database and you have to find it

Comment: @Tim Oh man! please post an answer so I could accept it, it worked using CSS, not JS, I simply override it

Comment: Glad you found a solution, I'm not sure what to put in the answer because I'm not sure what you've done haha. You just added your own CSS file with `.slick-slide { z-index: 0 !important;}`?

Comment: @Tim yes because no js worked and i was so frustrated and I read your comment saying add important, which i had already added in js and did not work, therefore i tried adding it in css exactly as you just said and it worked. I have no clue why but it worked 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested per comments above:

Simply override `.slick-slide` in your CSS with `!important`, no JavaScript required.

```
.slick-slide { 
    z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Edit:

`0` is simply a placeholder, choose a value you see fit or set to `initial` for the default value of z-index.

Comment: Just a note, `z-index:0`; is not the same as removing it. This div could be inheriting another z-index from parent, just for example, with a negative z-index and 0 would still give it higher specificity. Just for example of why it’s not the same.

Comment: I agree, 0 is simply a placeholder in this instance. Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery - use `Element.style.removeProperty()`:

```
document.querySelector(".slick-slide").style.removeProperty("z-index");
```

Comment: I was mid-way through typing out an epic, long, seriously awesome answer when I read this and thought "oh, there I go, overthinking it again". Just tested this out of curiosity and can confirm it works on in-line css. Good stuff!

Comment: your code is working perfectly, the only problem is that it's working only when I execute it from the console and is returning `999` however when I write it as code, it is not working.  That never happened to me before, in the console it works

Comment: I'll try to place it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I love it when people tell me I help them out.

Comment: Also @Lynob It may be that SlickSlider is interfering with your CSS and adding z-index when you try to remove it, because as Tim mentioned above, it works on inline CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have z-index as inline and want to remove it you should remove the whole style attribute instead.

```
`$('.slick-slide').removeAttr('style');`
```

I see that you are using Slick Slider. I recommend not to delete any styles served by Slick. Better to write an ugly override with some CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer but cannot accept it since I'm not sure it's the right answer.

The better solution is to set the parent div that you created

```
.example-banner { 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

And leave slick slider as is, that would fix the issue too. The difference is that if you do like the accepted answer suggested, like I suggested previously, you'll face an issue which is that if you click on any `href`, it will take you to the last `href` of the slider.

So lets say your slider has 5 slides and each slide has a link to an article, when you click on any of those links, you'd be taken to the last article.